# How to use civivolunteer description text

Tags: civivolunteer

On the civivolunteer role options page you can edit the roles and fill out a description field.  That is great but how do I use the description field on event pages where civivolunteer is enabled?  I just get a drop down box listing the label.  And obviously we can add description text to the event page, but that seems wrong.  Where is the role description displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The role description is currently used in two primary places.

On your volunteer opportunities page, you'll notice a small quote bubble next to each role that has a description defined.  Clicking the bubble will bring up a popup listing the description.

The other place the description is used is in the confirmation email sent to the volunteer after signup.